# Message Error instantiating servlet class [com.pkg.Myclass]

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

plz help me I am unable to find solution for this problem

```
// Servlet class
package com.pkg;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
public class Myclass implements Servlet{

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("init method");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>        
        <servlet-class>com.pkg.Myclass</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/web</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.pkg.Myclass]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Root Cause

java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.pkg.Myclass.(Myclass.java:1)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Comment: Which directory is this deployed to ?

Comment: ant -f C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1 -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1 run

Comment: what I was trying to get at is, has this class been deployed correctly to tomcat?

Comment: When deploy the project http://localhost:9494/WebApp/   page execute successfully on server but when I put '/web' then this error comes up.

Comment: *has this class been deployed correctly to tomcat?* - under tomcat there is a folder called webapps - below this folder, where is Myclass.class ?

Comment: I don't have Myclass.class  file under tomcat web apps folder

Comment: Study how to properly deploy to Tomcat

Comment: finally my error is solved thank you